# Laravel: Query to intermediate table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Suppose there are two tables with many to many relationship with each other.

```
users->id, name
skills->id, name
(intermediate table) skill_user->id, user_id, skill_id, custom
```

Now, i want to use this mysql query into eloquent form. What would be the eloquent form of below query?

> select count(*) from skill_user where user_id=1 and skill_id=2 and
>   custom="other"

Comment: Have you checked [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) - **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns**?

Comment: $users = DB::table('skill_user')
            ->where([ ['user_id', '=', 2],
             ['skill_id','=', 2]
             ['custom','=', other']
       
     ])
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->get();

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

*select count(* *) *from skill_user where user_id=1 and skill_id=2 and custom="other"*

```
$results = skill_user::where(['user_id'=>2,'skill_id'=>2,'custom'=>'other'])->get()->count();
```